# Run unison on startup

Tags: startup

I want to be able to run unison on startup, continuing indefinitely, without needing a terminal window open. How can I accomplish this?

I currently have to run the command `unison -ui text` in a terminal on startup, and keep that terminal window open for it to continue running.

Comment: You can try and create a `systemd` unit file as explained here: https://gist.github.com/thunfischbrot/0b6a21a84f166c4fa74fc5df4a470b17 , then run `sudo systemctl enable unison` and `sudo systemctl start unison`.

Answer (score 1):

As [Yaron](https://gist.github.com/thunfischbrot/0b6a21a84f166c4fa74fc5df4a470b17) posted in a comment, creating a systemd service worked.

Following [this guide](https://gist.github.com/thunfischbrot/0b6a21a84f166c4fa74fc5df4a470b17) I created a systemd service and activated it.

Please note for the guide above to work correctly you must ensure you add the following line to your unison `.prf` profile:

```
sshargs= -oIdentityFile=/path/tos/ssh/key/id_rsa
```

if you are `ssh`ing into the remote server